# How can I get the filename that a user uploads in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've created a pipeline to upload a file from the local to an agent. The filename that gets uploaded is the one set in the Stashed File Parameter. but, I want to use the filename that the user uploaded.

[my parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJfVB.png)

my pipeline script

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
parameters {
    stashedFile(name: 'inputFile', description: 'upload file')
    string(name: 'filename',defaultValue: 'uploadFile', description: 'filename')
}
node('test') {
    stage('upload file') {
        unstash 'inputFile'
        script {
            def fileName = params.filename
            if (fileName == "uploadFile"){
                def now = java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
                fileName = fileName + "${now}"
            }
            def status = sh(script: "mv ./inputFile /tmp/${fileName}", returnStatus: true)
            if (status != 0) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                error "can't upload file"
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The script works, but I want to remove the string parameter and instead use the filename of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/#plugin-content-accessing-original-upload-filename), the input file name will be stored in an environment variable of the format `<parameter_name>_FILENAME`. Based on that, in this case, the value would be present in a variable named `inputFile_FILENAME`, though it might be in all upper case. So to avoid confusion, if the parameter is renamed to something like `INPUT_FILE`, then the file name would be stored in the environment variable `INPUT_FILE_FILENAME`.